# Any DB/Schema design critique / assistance tool

Tags: sql, database, schema, rdbms, database-normalization

Is there any RDBMS Schema design assistance tool, which can check/critique the data-base design, suggest amends to improve normalization, suggest constraints, discover potential conflicts etc. ?

Note the idea is not so much of a diagramming tool, although if it is integrated in a diagramming tool, it would be swell. Alternatively, it could be something that works with SQL schema.

Preference would be towards FOSS tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can really develop a program that can do this ... it really depends on what you're building.  Normalization does not determine "good" design.

Answer (score 1):

TOAD is the most popular tool for this (sorry, not OSS).
http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/

It'll help you find some issues with your design, but it's not a magic bullet either.  Other than TOAD I haven't seen any other tool that comes close to being useful as opposed to manual auditing of the schema.  Any other ideas?